# Python Typing: How to Reference Dynamically Created Class in Type Hints

Tags: python, python-typing, textx

I'm trying to have an iterable of `TextXClass` instances for the implementation part of my meta-model but since that class is created dynamically, I'm out of luck. Is there still some clever way to type the individual elements of my model or will I have to essentially go with `Iterable[Any]`?

Comment: How is it created dynamically?

Answer (score -1):

You can simply create the class dynamically, and [forward reference](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#forward-references) it, by setting it in quotes. The link sais:

> When a type hint contains names that have not been defined yet, that definition may be expressed as a string literal, to be resolved later.

A minimal example:

```
def expect_class_instance(instance: "MyClass"):
    pass


def factory():
    class SomeClass:
        pass

    return SomeClass

MyClass = factory()
```